# I want all items present in ListBoxFor to controller in automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

This is my model:

```
public class ReportFilterEditViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    /..../
    public List<string> IncludedProducts { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my view

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.IncludedProducts,new SelectList(Model.IncludedProducts, "Name")})
<input type="submit" value="Save" id="saveFilter" class="button" />
```

The point is ... I want to pass to the controller all elements of the list without selecting them.
Help me please! Thanks in advance. 
Igor

Answer (score 0):

//first in Javascript in your View do the following :

```
 var data = [@Html.Raw(String.Join(",", Model.IncludedProducts.Select(i => "'" + i + "'")))];

//Pass the data array to the controller 

  $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetProducts", "Home")',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('Error while communicating with controller!');
                    }
            }).done(function (result) {
               // console.log(result.Success);
                    if (result.Success == 'true') {
                        console.log('sent to the controller');

                    }
                    else {

                        console.log("error sending data");
                    }
                });


//then in your Controller
[HttpPost]
Public JsonResult GetProducts(List<string> model)
{

//do whatever you want with the model coz that's your product list


}
```

Comment: First of all..Thanks for your comment ...But i can't change the controller...  public ActionResult Edit(ReportFilterEditViewModel model). I want to Pass all the values (including unselected) of a list box to MVC controller, i found this JS but  I can't adapt it to my purposes     $(document).ready(function () {
 
        $("#myForm").submit(function (e) {
 
            $("#myList option").prop("selected", "selected");
 
        });
 
    });

Comment: this script only does select all the elements in the list called myList, you need to send them back to the controller as I understood from your question, in this case YOU HAVE TO MAKE AN AJAX call! like illustrated above